# Bit confused between JavaScript Hoisting and Functional Scope

Tags: javascript

If I'm not wrong **var lives** is functional scope, because it's inside in function sandeep(). But if I'm doing console.log(lives) outside above the function then still I am getting console result as - **New Delhi** why? Can any one help me. (Is it because of Hoisting? it's moved on top...)

Screen shot without var define inside function
[image]

Screen shot with var inside function
[image]

Screen shot- write console.log after function call now it's giving undefined
[image]

I got my answer - It was my mistake, my chrome browser didn't refreshed properly. Thanks for every one for their answers.
[image]

```
console.log("Lives become global variable " + lives); 

function sandeep() {
    lives = "New Delhi";
    return lives;
}
sandeep();
```

Comment: because it's not `var lives`. it's `lives`. So it references to the global scope. EDIT: overread the "above". Sorry for that. No shouldn't work the way you described it. I receive an error

Comment: Bit confused about why you don't spell-check your post title.

Comment: If you start accepting answers given to your questions, which you are supposed to, you likely will attract more experienced users to answer.

Comment: @NisargShah Yes, and one should get error, if one understand how `console.log` works.

Comment: `Screen shot with var inside function` did you refresh the page, or do you still read the same global variable, that has been defined by your `Screen shot without var define inside function` before that?

Comment: @Joshua k I added here two screen shot (without var and with var inside function) and I'm not getting any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the fact that

> var lives is functional scope

But you haven't declare the variable in the function. You need to use `var lives = "New Delhi"` so that its scope is only in the function in which it is declared.

If you directly assign `lives = "New Delhi"`, it is assigned to global `window` object. Open browser console and try this.

`a = 1`
and then
`window.a`
You'll find that `window.a` is `1`.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes Abhinav, you are right, actually I was trying to understand what if I'm not defining var inside in function, will it be a functional scope or it will become global scope. I define var lives = "New Delhi" inside function. But if I'm doing console.log(lives) outside of the function, still I'm able to see "New Delhi"

Comment: Then you must have already declared variable in the console, otherwise it's not possible. Try in a new window.

Comment: Right Abhinav, my chrome browser didn't refreshed properly. It's lead me in confusion (whatever I learned for local and global scope). Thanks for your reply. One good lesson keep refresh your browser properly.

Comment: @Sandy absolutely :). One more request, if my answer helped you, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm not wrong var lives is functional scope

This is right but you forgot the `var` in front of lives. If you define it as a variable you will get an error:

```js
console.log("Lives become global variable " + lives); 

function sandeep() {
    var lives = "New Delhi";
    return lives;
}
sandeep();
```

Comment: OP had `var lives` when they originally posted the question. They probably removed it within the grace period. But I get the error in both cases.

Comment: @ Nisarg Shah I am not getting any error in both condition, please see my shared screen shot in question.

Answer (score 0):

Only **var** are working as global & functional scope.

**Global scope**

```
var x=5;
function callvar(){
 console.log(x);//5
 var x=3;
 console.log(x);//3
}
colsole.log(x);//3
```

**function scope:**

```
function one(){ var x = 5; 
 console.log(x)//5
}
console.log(x)// reference error

function two(){ var x = 4; 
 console.log(x)//4
}
console.log(x)// reference error
```

**let** & **const** are in block scope

functional scope is one type of block scope

```
 if(true){
   let x = 5; 
   console.log(x);//5
   }
console.log(x) // reference error
```